# MergeMap vs ConcatMap: can we get the best of both?

Tags: rxjs

In my application, I need to initiate a burst of long-running http requests which optimally should be allowed to resolve concurrently.  The results must be concatenated into a single observable for evaluation downstream.

Merging these observables using mergeMap allows for this concurrency, but this unfortunately does not guarantee order of the results.  ConcatMap guarantees order of the values emitted by the output, but it appears that the mapping operation for a given request is not executed until after its predecessor is completed, limiting concurrency to a single request at once (I'm not certain this is how it works but it would explain the result).

Before I start writing a custom operator, I thought I would ask: what is the best way to merge the results from a batch of requests, each returning an observable, while enabling concurrency and guaranteeing order of the results in the output observable?

Comment: Sounds like you want `forkJoin`

Comment: @BizzyBob forkJoin could work for most cases, but unfortunately it is not a pipeable operator, and incoming requests are streamed unpredictably.

Comment: It's possible to use `forkJoin` inside of another operator like `mergeMap` or `concatMap`.  It depends on the behavior you want though (*depends on what triggers the parallel  requests to refetch*).  If you share some example code, maybe I can give a more specific suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. First, you use map to map each event to a promise, this basicly fire off downstream process, then another concatMap to await for each promise sequentially.

```js
observer.pipe(
  map(e => request(e)),
  concatMap(e => e)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, the forkJoin / combineLatest (you would see the difference between these two by observing their marble diagram), you can get what you want.

How forkJoin works is, it will subscribe to EVERY observables parameter, wait until ALL observables complete, and then emit the value (order is determined by the order of parameter). https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

And yes, forkJoin is not a pipeable operator, because it's not. It will return an observable. So you can use it with switchMap/other higher order mapping.

Example

```
const studentsAndTeachers = school$.pipe(
   map(school=> school.id),
   switchMap(id => forkJoin(http.post('getStudents', id), http.post('getTeachers, id))
)

studentsAndTeachers will get you a tuple ([]) of students and teachers [[students], [teachers]]
```

Comment: I get that it can be used by an operator, but the relevant difference here is that, because it is not a pipeable operator, it doesn't operate on a pipe of incoming requests to be executed.  The "batch" of inputs must be known at execution time.  This is perhaps desireable in many cases, but any async pattern can handle this.  Where Rxjs excels is in pipeline construction where, if concurrency can be leveraged adequately, throughput is increased.

Comment: I solved the problem with a custom pipeable operator that combines a map to a new observable from an observable-to-promise conversion, followed by concatMap which maps to the result.  Order is preserved and the requests are allowed to execute concurrently, without restrictions on incoming requests.